# Prevent Parent From 'jumping' When Iframe Loads An Anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe with an src containing a hashed url. Every time I load the page, it jumps to the location of the iframe. How can I remove the jumping of the page?

Comment: [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan where should I put this? I tried placing it inside .load() but it still jumps. Thanks :)